# Jquery Hash Change - Ajax Form Back Button

Tags: jquery, hash, back-button, hashchange

I am using the Jquery Hash Change to manage my back button.

Link: [Jquery Hash Change](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/)

It works fine with a link ('a') is click, it adds the href as the hash.  Links work fine.

My question now is how do i get this to happen when my form button is clicked. I have form buttons that when clicked triggers an ajax call that processes my form and loads the success page (all without leaving the current page).  When the submit button is clicked to process the form, it does not create a hash so even though the form was processed, when the back button is click it jumps to the previous page instead of back to my form.

How do i add this functionality so that when forms are submitted via ajax i can get back to the form using the back button?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `window.location` object

set hash

```
location.hash='foooo';
```

get hash

```
var hash = location.hash
```

Set hash in success of form submit ajax

Comment: If possible can you explain with a little more detail.  i a am a newbie.  Thank you.

Comment: hard without you updating post with code you use to submit with

Comment: I have a normal html form.  have another page that the form submits to using jquery ajax.  That is really all to my page right now.

Comment: I can help but not without seeing the ajax method you are using to submit...there are numerous ways it can be coded